# TreeMap to ArrayList Java

Tags: java, android, list, treemap

I have a TreeMap which has a string key and the value part is a List with atleast four values.

```
Map<String,List<String>> mMap = new TreeMap<String,List<String>>();
```

I am using the tree map so that my keys are sorted. However after the sort I want to map this TreeMap to a listview. I want to convert the Map to a list and then build an Adapter for  listview. However I am not able to convert it when I do

```
ArrayList<String> trendyList = new ArrayList<String>(mMap);
```

It says: `The constructor ArrayList<String>(Map<String,List<String>>) is undefined`

Is there any other way I can do this?

Comment: `trendyList` should contain keys or values?

Comment: My Bad! It can only contain keys or values. However I am silly and I forgot this fact. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet!

Comment: In what way is this question android specific?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming you want a list of list of strings:

```
List<List<String>> trendyList = new ArrayList<>(mMap.values());
```

If you want to merge the lists then it becomes a bit more complex, you would need to run through the values yourself and do the merge.

To merge the lists:

```
List<String> trendyList = new ArrayList<>(); 
for (List<String> s: mMap.values()) {
   trendyList.addAll(s);
}
```

To merge the lists with keys:

```
List<String> trendyList = new ArrayList<>(); 
for (Entry<String, List<String>> e: mMap.entrySet()) {
   trendyList.add(e.getKey());
   trendyList.addAll(e.getValue());
}
```

**In Java 8 you get new tools for doing this.**

To merge the lists:

```
// Flat map replaces one item in the stream with multiple items
List<String> trendyList = mMap.values().stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

To merge the lists with keys:

```
List<String> trendyList = mMap.entrySet().stream().flatMap(e->Stream.concat(Stream.of(e.getKey()), e.getValue().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

A Map can be seen as a colleciton of key-value pairs, a list is just a collection of values. You have to choose if you now want your keys, then you use `keySet()` or if you want your values than you use `values()` wich returns a collection of `List<String>`